# how to Remove _id field while extracing mongodb document to json python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

how to remove _id field while extracting mongodb document to json python. I have written the code but getting nothing in json format.

**mongodb document looks like**

```
db.collection.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("612334997e2f032b9f077eb7"),
        "sourceAttribute" : "first_name",
        "domainAttribute" : "First_Name"
}
```

**Code tried**

```
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
mydb = myclient["guid"]
mycol = mydb["mappedfields"]

cursor = mydb.mycol.find({},{'_id':False})
list_cur = list(cursor)
json_data = dumps(list_cur, indent=1)
with open('mapping_files/mapping_from_mongodb.json', 'w') as file:
    file.write(json_data)
```

**Output Getting**

```
[]
```

**Expected output**

```
[
 {  
  "sourceAttribute": "first_name",
  "domainAttribute": "First_Name"
 }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

cursor = mycol.find({},{'_id':False})

mycol -> collection name.
_id should be in second braces.